# How to avoid 1 as boolean value in django template (1 is taking as boolean value Ture)?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My view is returning a dictionary.

```
**{'id': 1, 'user_info_id': 1, 'coding': False, 'testing': False, 'req_analysis': True}**
```

In Django template, I want to print all the keys of value == True. I have written the below code in Django template.

```
{% for key, value in db_data.0.items %}
    {% if value == True %} 
        {{ key }}
    {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

But, in output, I am getting key with value True as well as the keys with value 1.

```
O/P : 
id
user_info_id
testing
```

I want output as "testing" only.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`is`** operator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#is-operator) instead:

```
{% for key, value in db_data.0.items %}
    {% if value is True %} 
        {{ key }}
    {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

`is` checks if two objects are the *same* object. Whereas `==` checks if two objects are *equivalent*. For example in Python `1` and `True`; and `0` and `False` are considered equivalent:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> True == True
True
>>> 1 == 1
True
>>> True is True
True
>>> 1 is True
False
```

Comment: Thank you, man... its work perfectly ..... forget to check with " is " .... thanks a lot